# how to draw multiple googlechart from different datatable in one php file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pygooglechart

I want to draw a few charts from different datatables. The datatables are from queries in one PHP file called ajax.php.

This is the code:

```
//JOB POST BY SALARY
function jobsalary(){

global $DB;

//query by location total post
$sql = 'SELECT lcs.salaryrange_id, count(ljj.job_id) as count, lcs.salaryrange_item FROM {local_jobs_job} ljj INNER JOIN {local_cv_salaryrange} lcs ON ljj.job_salaryrangeid = lcs.salaryrange_id WHERE job_type = 0 GROUP BY lcs.salaryrange_item';


//get the query into record
$data = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);

//put the query into array
$rows = array();

$rows = array_map(function($item) {
return (object) ['c' => [
    (object) ['v' => $item->salaryrange_item, 'f' => null],
    (object) ['v' => intval($item->count), 'f' => null]
]];
}, array_values($data));


 // prepare return data
 $cols = [
(object) ['id' => '', 'label' => 'LABEL', 'pattern' => '', 'type' => 'string'],
(object) ['id' => '', 'label' => 'TOTAL', 'pattern' => '', 'type' => 'number'],
 ];


$returndata = new stdClass;
$returndata->cols = $cols;
$returndata->rows = $rows;

echo json_encode($returndata);

}

 //JOB POST BY JOB'S CATEGORY
 function jobcategory(){

 global $DB;

 //query by job's category total post
 $sql = 'SELECT ljc.category_id, count(ljj.job_id) as count, ljc.category_group FROM {local_jobs_job} ljj INNER JOIN {local_jobs_category} ljc ON ljj.job_categoryid = ljc.category_id  where ljj.job_type = 0 group by ljc.category_group';


 //get the query into record
 $data = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);

 //put the query into array
  $rows = array();

  $rows = array_map(function($item) {
  return (object) ['c' => [
    (object) ['v' => $item->category_group, 'f' => null],
    (object) ['v' => intval($item->count), 'f' => null]
  ]];
  }, array_values($data));


 // prepare return data
 $cols = [
(object) ['id' => '', 'label' => 'LABEL', 'pattern' => '', 'type' => 'string'],
(object) ['id' => '', 'label' => 'TOTAL', 'pattern' => '', 'type' => 'number'],
];


 $returndata = new stdClass;
 $returndata->cols = $cols;
 $returndata->rows = $rows;

echo json_encode($returndata);


}
```

The chart is drawn in another php file called report.php. This is the code:

```
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawItems);

    function drawItems(){
            var functionName = JSON.stringify({values:"joblocation"});
            var jsonPieChartData = $.ajax({
                            url: "ajax.php",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            data: "functionName",
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: false,

                            }).responseText;

                var piechartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonPieChartData);

                var optionsChart = {
                                //title: 'Job Posts by Location',
                                pieSliceText: 'label',
                                tooltip: {isHtml: true},
                                width: 500,
                                height: 300,
                                chartArea: { left:"5%",top:"20%",width:"90%",height:"90%" }
                              };

                // Instantiate and draw our pie chart, passing in some options.
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));


                //draw the chart      
                chart.draw(piechartdata, optionsChart);

                    }
```

But, I don't know how to call specific function for each chart using ajax call. Previously, I just draw one chart using one datatable in ajax.php file.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement create multiple ajax files and call all ajax files in one php file

Comment: I understand on creating multiple ajax call. But what do you mean to call all ajax files? it is only one file. But there are multiple functions in the file. I don't know how to call the function for each ajax call.

Comment: use GET method in Ajax and give the parameter to the url (under ajax ) and In other side check the parameter in your ajax.php file.On that basis call which function you want to call.

Comment: can you give an example? I do try some before but did not work